# filter posts based on menu_order

Tags: posts, wp-query, query

I want to filter posts (actually custom post type) based on `menu_order` like `menu_order >= 0` but I'm not able to find any way to do it.

I tried following ways but that did not work.

```
$query->set('menu_order', '>=0');
$query->query_vars['menu_order'] = '>=0';
```

I don't think I should be using `meta_query` or `tax_query`. But then how do I apply the required filter?

Basic need: I want to hide the posts if the `menu_order` is set to any -ve number. I want to use it as a flag to decide which posts should get displayed and which should not.

I know I can change the status to `Draft` and it will not get displayed but I was looking for alternative way and now I'm curious to know how to filter based on `menu_order`.

Comment: You probably have to hook into `posts_where` or do something similar to alter the query the way you want to. Personally I think it is better to use for example a custom taxonomy than "mis"using something that has another purpose.

Comment: Just to be explicit with what Nicolai is saying: It's not possible in WP_Query (and thus pre_get_posts) to filter results based on the `menu_order`. You'd need to modify the actual SQL with `posts_where`. And I agree that this would be a counterintuitive method for achieving it anyway. A custom field would probably be the way I'd go.

Comment: @Nicolai, @JacobPeattie I understand that it would be a misuse of `menu_order` and also understand that probably it will be an overkill to use `posts_where` filter for such a basic need. I just wanted to make sure that I'm not missing out on something obvious and hence I asked this question. Thanks for confirming my understanding :)

Comment: I wouldn't even say it's an overkill, just not the right tool for the purpose. Anyhow, you are welcome!